Why are Owner.x fields not populated in Case, Lead etc. created in Apex tests?
This is one of those "platform bug, or I'm being dumb" situations, so please help!
In a fresh scratch org containing no other customisation, I created the following tests to reproduce something weird I was seeing in a larger test.
@IsTest
private class CaseOwnershipTest {

    @IsTest
    static void caseTest() {
        Case testCase = new Case(Origin = 'Web');

        insert testCase;
        
        testCase = [SELECT OwnerId, Owner.Email FROM Case WHERE Id = :testCase.Id];

        Assert.areEqual(UserInfo.getUserId(), testCase.OwnerId);
        Assert.isNotNull(testCase.Owner.Email);
    }

    @IsTest
    static void leadTest() {
        Lead testLead = new Lead(Company = 'ACME', FirstName = 'Buggs', LastName = 'Bunny');

        insert testLead;

        testLead = [SELECT OwnerId, Owner.Email FROM Lead WHERE Id = :testLead.Id];

        Assert.areEqual(UserInfo.getUserId(), testLead.OwnerId);
        Assert.isNotNull(testLead.Owner.Email);
    }
    
    @IsTest
    static void accountTest() {
        Account testAccount = new Account(Name = 'ACME');

        insert testAccount;

        testAccount = [SELECT OwnerId, Owner.Email FROM Account WHERE Id = :testAccount.Id];

        Assert.areEqual(UserInfo.getUserId(), testAccount.OwnerId);
        Assert.isNotNull(testAccount.Owner.Email);
    }
}

The tests involving Lead and Case fail because Owner.Email is null. The Account one passes.
If I take the body of the Lead test or Case test and run it in anonymous Apex in the same org, it passes the assertion with no problems.
I assume that this is because Case and Lead can be owned by a Queue/Group whereas Account cannot.
Surely, the behaviour in the test should match the anonymous Apex, though?
And if I need to test code that queries Owner.Email on a Case, is that just impossible?
Update
Following @pchittum's comment, I tried running the tests with @IsTest(SeeAllData=true) and the tests do pass like that

Just curious as a further test to see what would happen, have you tried running the test with @IsTest(SeeAllData=True)? Like maybe the production data sequestering feature is somehow having a side-effect?

Thanks, Peter, that's a good thing to try. I tried it and updated the question to show that @IsTest(SeeAllData=true) does make the test pass.

Yeah...yikes...but you wouldn't want to have to do that just to get a test to pass that otherwise would work, eh? My vote is it's a corner case bug in the Apex test framework.

That other question is basically the same, you're right. I just didn't find it when I first searched. The answer here is more useful, IMO, than the one there.

This is a documented "feature":

When working with data silo Apex tests, cross-object field references
using the Owner relationship aren’t supported. Due to this limitation,
SELECT Owner.IsActive FROM Account returns null when run within a data
silo Apex test.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm
